# How to customise schedule board booking template for Dynamics 365 UCI

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I cannot seem to customise the booking template for the schedule board in the MSCRM field service

Comment: What exactly you want to customize?? Last time I tried for PSA and I was able to do that.

Comment: I just want to add WORK ORDER TYPE from work order and ADDRESS NAME from work order to be diplayed in the booking template.

Comment: @AnkUser I just want to add WORK ORDER TYPE from work order and ADDRESS NAME from work order to be diplayed in the booking template.Can you please help me .Thanks in advance

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/customize-the-schedule-board-urs-dynamics-field-service/

did you tired this, You need to customize HTML/XML file to display options and then fetchxml to filter result based on this.

One more Link here: https://community.dynamics.com/365/fieldservice/f/dynamics-365-for-field-service-forum/229311/customize-work-order-information-in-schedule-board-field-service

Comment: @AnkUser i have used all these methods in the current version with UCI and it does not work.I tried the same in classic and it works fine.

Comment: Ahh I did not know this catch. Need to Proof this on UCI